# How to embed C programs in an Android application

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm working on a software designed to compile and run on Linux. I was recently asked to cross-compile it for Android using the NDK, which was surprisingly straightforward.

To do this quickly, we just compiled the source, **without writing any JNI wrapper**. I copied the resulting binaries with `adb push` to an emulator (rooted) and ran it from the `adb shell`. Everything worked fine.

Now my question is: How can I embed those binaries somehow in an android application and run them (they act like services and must run in the background) ?

I'd like to avoid changing the existing code to support a JNI interface, but writting a small JNI/C code that just `exec` the other binaries is fine.

Bonus question: once embedded, is there a way to know the path of the installed binaries ?

Comment: If you want your app to work on non-rooted devices you need to use to NDK to build shared objects with some JNI glue to interface with the Java part of your app.

Comment: @Michael: that is what I was afraid of. So no way to directly "run" a embedded binary ? I guess I'll have to transform my binaries to a single `.so` file.

Comment: note writing the JNI code may be *much* easier than you think if you get SWIG to auto-produce it for you based on your header files

Comment: i think the idea is that all the C src goes into $PROJECT_DIR/jni/ along with Android.mk which is effectively your make file, run ndk-build and your lib.so will show up in $PROJECT_DIR/libs/armeabi/

Comment: you can run your binary however Android apps has a different lifecycle, so you can't keep it alive as a daemon. That's where you should start on thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/index.html
i found the nice tutorial in IBM developersworks about `Android NDK`